# capacitor copy resources to native apps

Tags: capacitor

I am using capacitor and trying to copy resources to native apps from `config.xml`.
I am using this:

```
   <platform name="ios">
        <resource-file src="www/certificates/certificate.cer" target="App/www/certificates/certificate.cer" />
```

but nothing gets copied.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The end result is that I want to be able to copy resource files to the native folders on compile so I don't copy them there manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Capacitor you are supposed to copy the files manually to the native projects because in Capacitor you commit the native projects.

Comment: I was trying to avoid copying manually to avoid situations where I might have to remove the natives from capacitor and add them again.

Comment: You are not supposed to remove the natives, ever. But you can always use node scripts to copy files if you want.